# using raspberry pi gpu for calculations in python

Tags: python, loops, raspberry-pi, gpu

Hello I am using raspberry pi to run a python code and I have this for loop in my code

```
    for i in range(len(nn)):

       xp=nn[i]%760
       yp=nn[i]/760

       x =index*3
       y = yp
       z = (xp-355)*2

       ff.write(str(x) +" " + str(y) + " " + str(z)+"\n" )
```

where `nn` is an array that contains indexes of pixels that we need to work on.

the problem is: when `nn` has more than 2000 item the for loop will take a long time.

the question is: how to make this work on raspberry pi GPU?

on my laptop I am using CUDA and the time about 0.

Comment: While I have no idea if it is possible (or how) to use the Raspberry's GPU "CUDA Style", why don't you do just `for n in nn: xp=n%760, yp=n/760, ...`? That would be way more pythonic

Comment: Instead of using the GPU your could try  Numpy (http://www.numpy.org/), to replace the for loop, e.g, ``xp = np.array(nn) % 760``  and so on.

Comment: Ooh thanks its work very good